# Django - Registration form not saving data in database

Tags: html, css, mysql, django-forms, csrf-token

There must be something wrong with the way I included {% csrf_token %} because I just won't manage to save data into my database. Does anyone know what is wrong with my files? It worked before I implemented the css styles. I don't get any errors and everything seems to work, just no data is saved when I look at my MySQL database.

```
# Views.py:

from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from .models import RegistrationData
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def register(request):
    context = {
        'form': RegistrationForm
    }
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)

def addUser(request):
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        myregister = RegistrationData(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                      password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
                                      email=form.cleaned_data['email'])
        myregister.save()
    return redirect('home')
```

```
# urls.py:

from django.urls import path
from .views import register, addUser

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    path('adduser/', addUser, name='addUser')
]
```

```
# register.html:

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %} Register {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/InputSubmit.css' %}">

<style>
    input[type=text], select {
        width: 20%;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin: 4px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    input[type=password], select {
        width: 20%;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin: 4px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    input[type=email], select {
        width: 20%;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin: 4px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    input[type=submit]:hover {
        background-color: #45a049;
    }
    div {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label><br>
    {{form.username}}<br>
    <label>Password</label><br>
    {{form.password}}<br>
    <label>Email</label><br>
    {{form.email}}
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <form action="{% url 'addUser' %}" method='post'>
        <input type='submit' value='Register' class='btn btn-success'>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
 </div>

{% endblock %}
```

```
# InputSubmit.ccs:

input[type=submit] {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 11px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
# models.py:

from django.db import models

class RegistrationData(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

```
# forms.py

from django import forms

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                   'placeholder': 'Your username...'
                                }))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                   'placeholder': 'Your password...'
                               }))
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
                            widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                                'class': 'form-control',
                                'placeholder': 'Your email address...'
                            }))
```